# Best way to "Clip" (saturate) a variable

Tags: c++, c, optimization, processor

What is the best (fastest) way to clip a variable using C++ on a modern processor. e.g. If it is below a value, clip it to that value.

I'm aware of a few ways to do it, however, branch prediction comes to mind about the speed. 
For example:

```
double ClipValue(double value)
{
  if (value < 0)
  {
    value = 0.0;
  }

  return value;
}
```

I would guess that the above would have to branch some of the time.

```
double ClipValue(double value)
{
  return value < 0.0 ? 0.0 : value;
}
```

This may not.

```
double ClipValue(double value)
{
  return std::max(value, 0.0);
}
```

And I'm unsure how this would behave.

I guess a lot of it comes down to the compiler and optimizations settings, but what is generally considered the fastest method to saturate a variable. I have used double in this example but I'm equally interested in integers.

Comment: With modern optimizing compiler you would probably get same or equivalent machine code for all these implementations.

Comment: Worrying about branch prediction in a high-level, compiled language seems a bit weird...

Comment: See math functions `floor` and `ceil`.